# How do I set object C1 to the input radius?

Tags: c++, class, object

I made an object of Circle called C1 and C2.

By default, I set the radius to 0 with the constructor, and then made an object C2 with a Radius of 5.

I want to input a radius and make the radius for C1 the user input
I can get the input, but unsure of how to remove the default value of C1 from 0 to user input, so my question is, how do i do it?
My code is as follows

inputRadius = 0; was there because it would give me an error while trying to call the function. This got rid of that error. My main concern is to get an input of radius c1 in place of the default 0

MAIN:

> ```
>  double inputRadius = 0;
>  Circle C1(0);
>  Circle C2(5);
>  getRadius(inputRadius);
>  Circle C1(inputRadius);
> ```

My header file is as follows.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

double getRadius(double inputRadius)    {
       cout << "Input the radius for the circle C1 ";
       cin >> inputRadius;
       return inputRadius;    }

class Circle    {
      public:
         Circle(double r)
         {
             setRadius(r);
         }
         void setRadius(double r)
         {
             radius = r;
         }
          double radius;    };
```

If made easier, I made a puu.sh link of the code
http://puu.sh/5HC0v.png and http://puu.sh/5HC2o.png

Comment: Why not just call `C1.setRadius(inputRadius);`?

Comment: @CommanderCorianderSalamander because inputRadius is not changed. getRadius don't need a parameter. i think you are serching for C1.setRadius(getRadius());

Comment: True that ^^ it would also make that function a hell of a lot more readable too

Comment: @CommanderCorianderSalamander Oh I just read itwasntpete 's answer. Will try that, because the function wasn't being called otherwise

Answer (score 2):

First if all, your function `getRadius` is weird and you use it in a wrong way. It is weird, because it takes some parameter but does nothing with it. And you use it in a wrong way, because it `returns` something and you ignore it.

Having a line:

```
getRadius(inputRadius)
```

reads the radius from the console, but it **doesn't store it** in the variable. The 'inputRadius' is an input-parameter for that function. It goes from the outside to the inside of the function, not the other way around. (although with pointers and references you can have a two-way parameters. but yours is just a 'double' so it's one-way.)

Trim that function to just:

```
double getRadius()
{
   cout << "Input the radius for the circle C1 ";

   double inputRadius; // added, because after removing the parameter
                       // you need some variable at hand to be able to
                       // read from cin

   cin >> inputRadius; // rest is just like you've had it
   return inputRadius;
}
```

and then call it and actually **store the result**:

```
double newValueOfRadius;

newValueOfRadius = getRadius();
```

now, having a variable with the radius that has been read from console, you can use it to create a new object:

```
Circle C1( newValueOfRadius );
```

or, you can set te radius of existing object

```
C2.setRadius( newValueOfRadius );
```

Comment: Okay, trying this now. will get back to you with results!

Answer (score -1):

You will have to use a `set` function to change the radius when the object is already creted since you cannot call a constructor upon an already existing object like you did here:

```
//THIS IS WRONG
Circle C1(0);
Circle C1(inputRadius);
```

The code should look like

```
class Circle
{
public:
     Circle(double r)
     {
         radius = r;
     }
     void setRadius(double r)
     {
         radius = r;
     }
private:
      double radius;   
};

void main()
{
    Circle C1(0);
    double r = 0;
    cin >> r;
    C1.setRadius(r);
}
```

Comment: C1 isn't set to inputRadius.

Comment: Oh my, wow thank you so much!! I wish I could up-vote the answer.

Comment: I understood the concept and answer, made a small change and it worked.
EDIT: It still did not change the value of C1

Comment: @ user2901840 I see now that you've made your radius field as public. Which means you don't even have to use functions, you can just do
 
C1.radius = input; But you usually want to make fields private and use set functions to change values

Comment: @Lazybeem , so i should use setRadius and make my fields private to that specific function/class?

Comment: @user2901840 I have edited my answer. In general all fields should be private, your constructor will set a default value/the given value and if you'd like to change the field in the future you will make a set function for that. then you can change the radius whenever you like whether from user-input or a value you choose.